# 60fps 4k video low performance

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video, display-resolution

My laptop runs Ubuntu 16.04 and has the following specs:

- SSD 256
- i5 7200u
- 8 gb RAM
- nvidia Nvidia GeForce GTX 950M

So ... it properly plays 30fps 4k video on YouTube, but it freezes when I try to play 60fps 4k video though there was no such an issue with it on *Windows 10*.

I tried different drivers ...
and even different browsers ...
but it still works properly only on Windows ...
but I don't want to go back to Windows!

**Further Info:**
After having a conversation with NVIDIA support - it was found out that upon YouTube 4k play - Ubuntu highly uses CPU like on this *System monitor screenshot*:

[image: System monitor screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/enable-hardware-acceleration-in-chrome.html) provides some good (mostly still relevant) steps:

Basically, if using Chrome, go to:

```
chrome://gpu
```

You will see a list of GPU features the browser can use.  On my up to date Intel graphics system, I see this:

```
Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
```

I expect you probably see something similar.  You can try the suggestions on that link of getting video decode working, but I can tell you that you might not get it all working, and it also might not be stable (graphics errors, crashes, etc).  The options to change are all in:

```
chrome://flags (option: "Override software rendering list")
```

Again, be warned, these can destabilize your browser performance.

The Ubuntu Desktop team has also been working on this problem and has a call for testing out for [18.04 for Intel](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-video-playback-in-18-04/3888).  In case anyone gets to this question/answer and has other graphics cards.

Comment: Upvoted your answer but wonder if there have been any new developments over the last year?